# Why it keeps me asking am i root?

Tags: 14.04, root

When ever I try to install "dh-modaliases", why i am getting this answer:
"fahadhemu@hemu:~$ apt-get install dh-modaliases
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?" please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run apt-get without root privileges, try the same command with sudo:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases
```

Comment: ...Because you need to be root to use apt-get.

in gnu-linux, when you perform action that will change important things in the sistem (like install programs), you must perform that action like a sistem amministrator (root), not as a normal user :)